# Перевод строки в числа побуквенно

Tags: python, строки

Задача из кодевара. Нужно перевести строку в числа, где числа соответствуют номеру буквы.
Решил таким образом

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def alphabet_position3(text):
    if type(text) == str:
        text = text.lower()
        result = ''
        for letter in text:
            if letter.isalpha() == True:
                result = result + ' ' + str(alphabet.index(letter) + 1)
        print(result.lstrip(' '))
```

Были намного более элегантные решения, но вот одно, осталось мне не понятным

```
def get_positions(text):
    for char in text:
        pos = ord(char)
        if pos >= 65 and pos <= 90:
            yield pos - 64
        if pos >= 97 and pos <= 122:
            yield pos - 96

def alphabet_position5(text):
    print(" ".join((str(char) for char in get_positions(text))))

alphabet_position5("some text here")
```

Откуда эти все значения: 65,90,64..., с которыми происходит сравнение.

Comment: Из [таблицы ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: @ Sergey Gornostaev Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Коды заглавных букв A-Z = (65-90)
Коды строчных букв  a-z = (97-122)

Соответственно если буква заглавная то ее номер по порядку=ord("Заглавная буква")-64 
Пример для "A": ord("A")=65. Соответственно 65-64=1.

Тоже самое для строчных
номер строчной буквы по порядку = ord("Строчная буква")-96 
Пример для "а": ord("а")=97. Соответственно 97-96=1.

Можно думать про это как про то, что номера всех заглавных букв смещенны относительно их порядка в алфавите **на 64** симлова
А номера строчных **на 96**

**Номера строчных букв**

```
for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print(i,ord(i))
```

**Номера заглавных букв**

```
for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print(i.upper(),ord(i.upper()))
```

Comment: chr() - операция, обратная ord(). И можно не делать список букв, а просто пройтись по числам через range().

Comment: Можно, но станет ли от этого понятнее почему сравниваються с значениями 65,90,64?

Comment: Не вижу причин, почему нет.